# Update bindings to var properties in QML

Tags: qt, qml

If you take a look at [this page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-var.html) it notes that bindings to var properties are not automatically updated when the object changes:

```
Item {
    property var car: new Object({wheels: 4})

    Text {
        text: "The car has " + car.wheels + " wheels";
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        car.wheels = 6;
    }
}
```

That will say "The car has 4 wheels" because `car.wheels = 6;` doesn't automatically trigger an update.

What the page doesn't say is how to work around this? How can I manually trigger an update (without replacing the whole `car` object).

**Edit:** To be clear, I don't want to replace the whole `car` object, and I *do* want to use a `property var` (my actual property is a javascript object that can't be stored in any of the native QML property types).

**Edit 2:** Here is an example using `QtObject` that *doesn't* work (it says "The car has 0 wheels.":

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    property var car: QtObject { property var wheels: [] }

    Item {

        Text {
            text: "The car has " + car.wheels.length + " wheels";
        }

        Component.onCompleted: {
            car.wheels.push("Rear-left");
            car.wheels.push("Rear-right");
            car.wheels.push("Front-left");
            car.wheels.push("Front-right");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After reading [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-variant.html#storing-arrays-and-objects) I don't think it's possible. But one thing you could do is to reassign only the array instead of the whole object after data manipulation: `car.wheels` = `car.wheels` after pushing the elements. At least better than replacing the whole object. But it depends on how your data is structured...

Comment: Yeah or I thought about adding a dummy property, something like: `property bool update`, and then "use" it in my expression like `text: "Blah blah" + (update ? "" : "")`. Then to update manually just do `update = !update` or something like that. Massive hack though.

Comment: FYI, assigning the `car` back to itself also works at the end of the `Component.onCompleted` block like `car = car;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the page *does* say how to work around this:

> If the onCompleted handler instead had "car = new Object({wheels: 6})"
>   then the text would be updated to say "The car has 6 wheels", since
>   the car property itself would be changed, which causes a change
>   notification to be emitted.

Though I suppose that goes against your requirement of not replacing the whole `car` object.

That being said, there is (at least) one other option -- use a [QtObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qtobject.html):

```
Item
{
    property var car: QtObject { property int wheels: 4 }

    Text {
        text: "The car has " + car.wheels + " wheels";
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        car.wheels = 6;  // This will update the text
    }
}
```

### Edit

Given the new example, the code you've listed won't trigger an update if you need to use a Javascript array containing a basic type.  However, if you are able to use a `list` containing a QML type, you can use the following workaround:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    property var car: QtObject { property list<Item> wheels }

    Component
    {
        id: wheelComponent
        QtObject
        {
            property var wheelName;
        }
    }

    Text
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        text: "The car has " + car.wheels.length + " wheels";

        Component.onCompleted:
        {
            var wheel = wheelComponent.createObject(window, {"wheelName": "Rear-left"} );
            car.wheels += wheel;
        }
    }
}
```

This may be heavy-handed for your needs.  The hack approach of creating a `property bool update` and altering it whenever you change the array may be preferable.

Comment: Yes I don't want to replace the whole `car` object. And using `QtObject` just shifts the problem - you're now using a `property int` instead of a `property var`. My actual object is a multidimensional matrix so I have to use `property var`.

Comment: @Timmmm It works even if `wheels` is `property var`.  However, I'd need to see an example of your multidimensional matrix to know if `QtObject` would work here.

Comment: It seems to work if `wheels` is a non-object JS value (i.e. double or string), but not if it is anything more complicated, e.g. an `Array`. I added an array example to my question. Cheers for the help btw.

Comment: @Timmmm I've updated by answer, though it may not meet your needs.

Comment: Creating a new object is heavy handed, but you can trigger the update notification by simply assigning `car = car`, which should hopefully  not create a new object.

Answer (score 2):

Notifications and automatic binding reevaluations are only supported for QML properties, not for JS object members.

For a JS object inside a var, the notification will only be triggered if the actual object changes with another object, but not when the object changes internally.

You can however force the bindings to reevaluate, by manually emitting `carChanged()` after an internal object change has been made.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved identical problem in this way:

```
Item {
    property var car: new Object({wheels: 4})

    Text {
        Connections {
            target: car
            onWheelsChanged: {
                text: "The car has " + car.wheels + " wheels";
            }   
        }

        text: "The car has " + car.wheels + " wheels";
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        car.wheels = 6;
    }
}
```