# How can I bind to a field on a nested object in QML such that update notifications propagate when that field is set?

Tags: qt, qml

If I have QML object with objects inside of it that also has objects inside of it, how can I bind to an inner object's field such that setting that field in one part of QML propagates the new value to other parts of the QML that are listening to it?

Given this toy example:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width:150;
    property var p;
    Component.onCompleted: {
        p = {'c':{'gc':{'ggc':'field_val'}}};
    }

    Label { text : "p.c.gc.ggc="+p.c.gc.ggc; }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent;
        onClicked: {
            console.log("setting p.c.gc.ggc = 'new_val';")
            p.c.gc.ggc = 'new_val';
        }
    }
}
```

The code initially displays what is expected:

[image]

When I click the window, QML prints out, per my `console.log`:

```
qml: setting p.c.gc.ggc = 'new_val';
```

However, the `Label` text doesn't update to `p.c.gc.ggc=new_val`

Next, if I add the following line after `p.c.gc.ggc = 'new_val';`:

```
p = p;
```

The edit is propagated to the `Label` and I see:

[image]

However, it seems like a hack.  Am I missing some mechanism?  Shouldn't updates to a nested object structure automatically replicate to other parts of the QML code?

Comment: take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30891343/update-bindings-to-var-properties-in-qml)

Comment: Genuinely curious: why do you need to store this kind of data in QML?

Comment: I have a tree of data that I'm fetching from SQLite and using http requests in C++.  I don't want to create a bunch of C++ helper objects, because connecting C++ <--> QML is laborious.  Thus, I'm passing the top container back and forth.  The data looks like `SampleSet { variety : foo, ... , sub_samples: [  SampleSet { property1: blah, property2: blah,  ... } , SampleSet{ ... }, ... ] }`.  The input controls need to connect to the top level properties and  then, in a `ListView`, connect to each child property using input controls.